# Gather column names from an Excel spreadsheet in Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, google-sheets-api

I've got a spreadsheet that I'm loading into a Java program using `org.apache.poi`. Loading the data is fine, but i'm concerned the columns may be re-arranged at times, which would cause issues with my code. The program expects data to be in a specific column order.

There is a row that contains the column names that I have been tossing away. Is there a way to tell the `SpreadSheet` object that I do have a named set of columns that I can index against?

For example, I'd like to load object data like so(psuedo code):

```
myObject.setName(row.getCell('columnName'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (not tested), if the name of the columns are in row 0 :

```
public short getCellIdx(Row nameRow, String colName) {
    for (short idx = nameRow.getFirstCellNum(); idx <= nameRow.getLastCellNum(); idx++) {
        if (rownameRowgetCell(idx).equals(colName))
            return idx;
    }
}
```

and then

```
Row nameRow = sheet.getRow(0);
myObject.setName(row.getCell(getCellIdx(nameRow, "columnName")));
```

If you have a bigger set of columns, you may better hash the column names to a Hashmap or similar.

Comment: I was thinking of doing the HashMap if there wasn't a nice `poi` solution

Comment: No, not one that I am aware of. If so, they'd probably also do it that way.